# How can I add tags to an image with hover effects?

Tags: html, css

All Im trying to accomplish this feature where there are little tags on an image and when you hover over the tag it shows the product used see pic,

[image]

I was thinking of having an link map over the image and just put the coordinates in of where I want the link to go but just thought there maybe another option about.

Comment: You already posted one valid solution. Anything else is an opinion-based discussion…

Comment: You can also use absolute positioning.